# About the differentiability of a Weierstrass-like function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let we consider: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2^nx)}{n^2}$$
Since $\left|\sin x\right|\leq 1$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}<2$, the above series is uniformly convergent and $f(x)$ is a continuous function. The series associated with the formal derivative, $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^n\cos(2^n x)}{n^2}$, looks like it is not convergent for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it sufficient to prove this fact, to deduce that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at any $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Ok.  I considered it.  You should probably ask a question.

Comment: @MrYouMath Your conclusion is not true.

Comment: @Epsilon: you are right :).

Comment: Question improved in order to actually make sense (and be quite interesting, too). I hope you do not mind.

Answer (score 2):

We may consider that
$$ f(x)-f(y) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2\cos\left(2^n\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(2^n\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}{n^2} \tag{1}$$
If $|x-y|\approx 2^{-k}$, we may split the above series according to $n\leq k$ or $n>k$.
The part corresponding to $n>k$ does not really matter since its contribute is bounded.
The part corresponding to $n\leq k$ can be approximated through $\sin(x)\sim x$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, and we do not even need to be extremely accurate to prove that by the previous approximation,
$$ \lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\tag{2} $$
does not exist for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So the answer to your question is "*essentially, yes*", but a little care is needed in dealing with details. Here it is an approximated graph of $f(x)$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$:

$\hspace1in$[image]

as expected, it is continuous but full of "spikes".